# Using Node.js's REPL eval with an async function

Tags: node.js, async-await, read-eval-print-loop, node-repl

I am using the [Node.js REPL module](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#replstartoptions) to implement a REPL.

Here's how I start the REPL:

```
const cli = repl.start({ eval: evals });
```

I have a function, `answer`, that takes a few arguments and returns the answer. `answer` is async. `evals` is a function that bridges what REPL needs for the `eval` function with what my `answer` function provides. `evals` looks at follows.

```
const evals = (command, context, file, callback) => {
  (async () =>
    callback(null, await answer(command, arg1))
  )()
};
```

Now, the good thing is, it works. But this looks far more complicated than it needs to be. Am I missing some way to make this considerably simpler to maintain?

(Here is the [code in context](https://github.com/vrandezo/lambda-cli/blob/master/src/interactive.js#L60))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making the evals function directly async should work:

```
const evals = async (command, context, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, await answer(command, arg1));
};
```

Or you could avoid async/await and use `Promise.then` directly; that might be clearer in this case:

```
const evals = (command, context, file, callback) => {
    answer(command, arg1)
        .then((result) => callback(null, result));
};
```

(In either case you could probably omit the braces, though I’m not sure if I like that better or not.)

Comment: Thanks! That totally worked! And removes quite a bit of syntax, thank you!